Speed up json aggregation in postgres
I have a plain table which looks like this:
| uid   | search_qeury    | search_ts                         |
|-------|-----------------|-----------------------------------|
| uid_1 | {"key1":"val1"} | 2024-08-16 08:06:26.283557 +00:00 |
| uid_2 | {"key2":"val2"} | 2024-08-16 08:06:26.283557 +00:00 |

DDL:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_searches
(
    uid                varchar      NOT NULL,
    search_query       json         NOT NULL,
    search_ts          timestamptz  NOT NULL
);

What I need to do is to aggregate these values into a new table with columns: uid, searches_4h, searches_8h, searches_12h
So I wrote a code that does that in that way:
SELECT
    uid,
    JSON_AGG(search_query) FILTER (WHERE search_ts > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '4' HOUR)  AS searches_4h,
    JSON_AGG(search_query) FILTER (WHERE search_ts > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '8' HOUR)  AS searches_8h,
    JSON_AGG(search_query) FILTER (WHERE search_ts > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '12' HOUR) AS searches_12h
FROM users_searches
WHERE search_ts > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '12' HOUR
GROUP BY uid

but it tooks around 10 minutes to complete. I am wondering if there is any more optimized way to do that. Thank you

Run an explain query and figure out what’s going on

Attach output of explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for that query as well as DDL for the table and indexes you have on it.

Is there an index on search_ts ?

There is no index for search_ts since table keeps data for only 13 hours (it is cleaned periodically).

The post lacks sufficient information upon which to base suggestions. Besides the table DDL (including indexes) and the output from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,SETTINGS,VERBOSE), please tag the actual PostgreSQL version and add data statistics; e.g., number of rows, min/max/mean length of search_query, number of unique uid values, and mean number of rows per uid. I've modeled the data using 10000 unique uid, a mean of 1000 searches per user, a seach value of ~100 characters, randomly spread across 13 hours. Running PostgreSQL 16 on a 2017 MacBook Pro, the query completes in ~27 seconds.
